# Center JTable's cells to the middle of the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, centering, border-layout

How to center `JTable` cells to the middle of the `JTable`?

I am using table to paint boxes in the table, but when resized, the cells remain left-top aligned. When the table fits the cells nicely, it is not a problem. But when I resize the window (and the table with it), it is wrong:

[image: fine looking][image: wrong]

My question is, is it possible to make the cells appear in the middle of the table? I suppose I could use glues on sides (this is `BorderLayout`), but I would rather take this approach.

Comment: *"I am using JTable to paint boxes in the table,.."*  Why abuse `JTable` for what seems like purely a rendering thing?  What is this for?

Comment: I try and use a layout manager that allowed you to fill vertically, but also align the component horizontally. Something like GridBagLayout

Comment: *"I could use glues on sides (this is `BorderLayout`)"*  No you couldn't, glue is not a concept that applies to `BorderLayout`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am just doodling around making something tetris-like. JTable seemed a good component for this, since it allows me to paint individual cells and I need a 10x20 matrix for painting. 2) Okay, sorry. I don't know much about layouts so far.

Comment: *"I am just doodling around making something tetris-like."*  `JTable` is entirely unsuited to that.  Use custom painting and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `TableCellRenderer` is just painting colored blocks, you could put the table in a `FlowLayout` and override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`.

```
private static final int WIDE = 10;
private static final int HIGH = 20;
private static final int SIZE = 50;
...
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
    return new Dimension(WIDE * SIZE, HIGH * SIZE);
}
```